# OpenNI2: Reading in .oni Recording

Tags: c++, openni

I was hoping someone could provide some direction on how I could go about reading in a previously recording .ONI file generated using OpenNI2. The current path that I'm on suggested that I pass my file in to the device and that it could handle the file and read from it instead of the camera. Something like:

```
Device device
rc = device.open("C:/Somefolder/depth.oni");
```

Currently any variation of this simply fails to load a device. Any suggestions are always much appreciated!

Comment: Try to check the NiViewer tool (it is in the sources) [NiViewer](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2/tree/master/Source/Tools/NiViewer) Also, if you can, check if the file is not corrupted or anything (using this tool to load it will tell you that)

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following assuming you have file_name which is a string:

```
//all variables needed
openni::Device device_;         
openni::VideoStream ir_;      
openni::VideoStream color_;    
openni::Status rc_;
openni::VideoFrameRef irf_;
openni::VideoFrameRef colorf_;

openni::OpenNI::initialize (); 
const char *cstr = file_name.c_str();
device_.open(cstr);
ir_.create (device_, openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
ir_.start ();
device_.setImageRegistrationMode (openni::IMAGE_REGISTRATION_DEPTH_TO_COLOR);
color_.create (device_, openni::SENSOR_COLOR);
color_.start ();
ir_.readFrame (&irf_);
color_.readFrame (&colorf_);
```

The last two functions read the depth and rgb frames. 
Setting the registration mode, if supported, will align depth and rgb :)

Comment: How would you set the filename?

Comment: You mean to store the files? you can just write them using  an ofstream. If you mean how to open the device you can do device.open( openni::ANY_DEVICE )